# Question on "wer weiß, ob es mir nicht gelang" from Fidelio

Tags: verb

The question is on *gelang* as occurring in these lines from Beethoven's Fidelio.

> JAQUINO
> Es ward ihr im Ernste schon bang;
> wer weiß, ob es mir nicht **gelang**.
> Wenn ich diese Tür heute
> nicht schon zweihundertmal
> aufgemacht habe, so will ich
> nicht Jaquino heißen.
> Zum Wetter, schon wieder!

Here Jaquino is soliloquizing on his unrequited love.

I am assuming that line 2 means something like:

> Who knows whether I might not succeed.

**QUESTION**

1. What is the standard way to say, 'Who knows whether I might not succeed?'  Is it:

   > wer weiß, ob es mir nicht *gelingt*, *gelang*, *gelinge* oder *gelänge*?
2. If the standard way is not 'wer weiß, ob es mir nicht *gelang*,' how should I account for line 2?  Does it mean something other than what I assumed it to?  Is 'gelang' there to rhyme with 'bang' though not the standard thing to say?

**BACKGROUND**

Full libretto can be found at:

[https://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~weber/opera/LIBLIB/fidelio.htm](https://www.cs.hs-rm.de/%7Eweber/opera/LIBLIB/fidelio.htm)

http://www.opera-guide.ch/opera.php?id=29

http://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/beethoven-beethovens-opera-fidelio-german-text-with-an-english-translation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the sentence is to be interpreted as "Who knows whether I might not succeed?", it should read

   > wer weiß, ob es mir nicht gelänge

("gelänge" instead of "gelingt" reflecting the uncertainty of "might"). The author would have taken some artistic licence to match "gelang" with "bang".

2. A direct translation would be "Who knows if I didn't succeed?". Jaquino notices that Marzelline is anxious ("Es ward ihr im Ernste schon bang"). Maybe he wonders if he has succeeded at last in changing her mind, thus causing this noticable anxiety.

I can't tell you how to interpret the libretto, but I think both would be viable.

Comment: I really like the simple, elegant solution of "didn't succeed."  In the opera Marzelline's "nein, nein, nein, nein" seemed so absolute that my mind just could not assign this degree of hope to Jaquino.

Comment: You're massively underestimating the capacity of obsessed lovers for unwarranted hope.